# How to get the date from jQuery UI datepicker (yes...again)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am a beginner here and cannot seem to get the value out of my "inline" datepicker to be used latter as an 'attribute' with a value 'date'.  If I use the 'input' instead of the inline (called with div) then I have no problems and my conditional check also works.

But trying to make the conditional check and return the selected date as the 'date' attribute doesn't work.

Can someone please suggest the correction I need to make to the code below? Very grateful for any help.

```
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js' | script_tag }}

<div style="clear:both;">
  <p>
<label for="date">Select DELIVERY DATE:</label>
<div id="date" type="hidden" name="attributes[Delivery Date]" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}"/>
<span style="display:block" class="instructions"> </span>
```

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
    minDate: 0, 
    maxDate: '+3M',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: noSunday
      });
      function noSunday(date){
          var day = date.getDay();
                  return [(day > 0), ''];
      }; 
});
</script>

<script>
jQuery("#date").datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method
   }
});
</script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('input[name="checkout"], input[name="goto_pp"], input[name="goto_gc"]').click(function() {
        if (jQuery('#date').val() == '') {
            alert("You must pick a delivery date before proceeding to checkout");
            return false;
        } else {
            jQuery(this).submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions. *"Does not work"* is a pretty useless statement as well.

Answer (score -1):

To get the date of a jQueryUI datepicker, you have to call `getDate` on it like this:

```
var currentDate = $(".selector").datepicker("getDate");
```

`currentDate` is a javascript `Date` object (not a `string`).

If you want to make some operations, checks, ... on dates, I suggest you to take a look to MomentJS (http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thank you ADreNaLiNe-DJ.. This helped put me in the right direction.